# Minimum replications for adequate testing power with factorial design

Tags: r, statistical-power, fractional-factorial

I currently running an agricultural field study using a 2x2x3 factorial design.  I need to collect samples for measuring soil bulk density, which takes a lot of time.  There are two sites, 4 replicates per treatment group, and controls added for reference, so in total there are 128 plots to collect a single sample from.  This would be a large undertaking, so I would like to conduct a power analysis to determine if I can collect fewer samples, like 2 replicates per treatment group.

Is it difficult to conduct power analysis for factorial designs?  I found a R package `Superpower` ([link to info](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Superpower/vignettes/intro_to_superpower.html)) , which I have yet to dive into.  Are there other options for conducting this analysis?  I can also use SAS for this purpose.

In the event someone who reads this knows how to do this analysis efficiently, I'll provide the some information and desired parameters.  Soil bulk density (BD) is measured as the dry weight of soil divided by the known volume.  BD can vary by soil type, but for the soil I'm working on, it can vary from 1.5-1.9 grams per cubic centimeter (g/cm3).  Based on [this tutorial](http://www.biostathandbook.com/power.html), I would like to be able to detect an effect size of 5%, with an alpha of 0.05 or 0.1, beta or power of 80%, and the standard deviation observed from prior data was 0.1 g/cm^3.